# -bash: sudo: command not found

Tags: debian, apt, sudo, su

I am trying to deploy django app.
When I print 
`apt-get update`
I see

```
W: Unable to read /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/ - DirectoryExists (13: Permission denied)
W: Unable to read /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ - DirectoryExists (13: Permission denied)
W: Unable to read /etc/apt/sources.list - RealFileExists (13: Permission denied)
E: List directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial is missing. - Acquire (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to read /var/cache/apt/ - opendir (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to read /var/cache/apt/ - opendir (13: Permission denied)
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

When I print  `sudo apt-get update`
I see

```
-bash: sudo: command not found
```

I tried to use `su` instead of `sudo`.
But it is strange. 
For example I print `su apt-get update`
And nothing happens
I just see a new line,

```
(uiserver):u78600811:~$ su apt-get update
(uiserver):u78600811:~$
```

The same if I try to install some packages.
What do I do?

If it is useful info - I am using Debian

```
(uiserver):u87600811:~$ uname -a
Linux infong1559 3.14.0-ui16294-uiabi1-infong-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.14.79-2~ui80+4 (2016-10-20) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Is this a customer account on a commercial server?

Comment: @tomas yeah////

Comment: If you don't own the server, what made you think you have the right to install or remove software? *ask the admin*

Comment: What happens if you run `apt-cache policy sudo` ? Not all Linux distros install sudo by default (Debian, for instance, will install sudo if and only if you don't specify a root password on installation). You can run apt-cache without root privileges.

Answer (score 225):

By default sudo is not installed on Debian, but you can install it. First enable su-mode:
`su -`

Install sudo by running:
`apt-get install sudo -y`

After that you would need to play around with users and permissions. Give sudo right to your own user.

`usermod -aG sudo yourusername`

Make sure your sudoers file have sudo group added. Run:
`visudo` to modify sudoers file
and add following line into it (if it is missing):

```
# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

You need to relogin or reboot device completely for changes to take effect.

Comment: This should be accepted answer, this solved my problem

Comment: I am getting "su: Cannot determine your user name." on doing su -

Comment: @user674669 have you checked this post: https://serverfault.com/questions/816969/cannot-determine-your-user-name ?

Comment: Thanks @MaksimLuzik. Mine is a docker container. The ideas on that page aren' helpful to me. Maybe, I should post a separate question.

Comment: Is It safe to give my user sudo permissions?

Comment: If it is just a normal user, then no. Only if you trust and know that the user needs to perform administrative tasks etc.

Comment: So Debian doesn't have sudo but it has su mode? What is su mode?

Comment: In short: su switches you to the root user account. Sudo runs a single command with root privileges.

Comment: if you get the `package not found` error, run `apt-get update` first. and then `apt-get install sudo`.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me.

Comment: As this is Debian, it would be better to use `adduser yourusername sudo`.

Comment: incase you can't find `usermod` , pls check in `/usr/sbin/`

Answer (score 20):

`su` and `sudo` are two different, but related commands.  It is unusual for `sudo` not to be installed, but it may simply not be in your Path.  Try `/usr/bin/sudo command`.

If indeed `sudo` is not available, you need as you surmised to use `su`, but it does not work in the same way as `sudo`.  The simplest way to use it is to simply run:

```
su -
```

This will ask you for the `root` user's password, at which point you should probably `apt install sudo`, log out of the root shell, and then proceed as normal.

Mind that unlike `sudo`, which asks you for **your** password, `su` will ask you for **root**'s password.

Comment: when I write su - nothing happens - just new line

Comment: Then you're probably already root.  Check with `whoami`.  If you're root, `apt install sudo` as described.

Comment: (uiserver):u78600811:~$ apt install sudo

Comment: W: Unable to read /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/ - DirectoryExists (13: Permission denied)
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?

Comment: @user2950593 if you're root then the prompt string will be `#`, not `$`

Comment: Depending on what `PS1` is set to.

Answer (score 19):

Since it's a commercial server you won't have access to root account nor be able to operate with root privileges. This means you won't be able to run `sudo` nor install packages. What you can try to do is:

- Check if you have access to a compiler and compile what you want for yourself and in your home space.
- Check if you can run a virtual machine. This might let you run your private instance of an OS, on which you would install packages.

Answer (score 1):

In a new Debian server install I too found out that `sudo` is not installed by default, but it can be done as root:

```
$ su root
# apt install sudo
```

What puzzled me is that I still got errors  with `visudo` and `usermod`:

```
# visudo
bash: visudo: command not found

# apt install visudo
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package visudo
```

Actually, `visudo` is included with the sudo package, it was just not in the `PATH` for root:

```
# dpkg -S visudo
sudo: /usr/sbin/visudo
sudo: /usr/share/man/man8/visudo.8.gz
```

So I added it to the root's `~/.bashrc`.

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/sbin
```

Now it can find `visudo` and `usermod` which can be used to [setup sudo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/425664/212177) access.