# Getting bash: wpa_supplicant: command not found

Tags: debian, wpa-supplicant

I am trying to connect to my school's wifi on a fresh install of Debian 10. I have no GUI and no internet at the moment, so just going through command line. I have set up my `/etc/wpa_supplicant.config` and found my wireless driver and set the link.

Now I am trying to run command `wpa_supplicant -B` and `dhclient` but both return not found. They're both downloaded (as evident using `whereis` command). Do I need to update some paths? I am in root.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/552416/fresh-installed-debian-10-no-internet-access-wlan0-command-not-found-whereis ?

Comment: This is a separate problem, so I made a different post for this issue specifically.

Comment: Since debian 10, simply escalating to root using `su` will make some commands unavailable due to the path issues. This may be the issue you are having. Try running them with `sudo command` or escalate to root via `su -`, if this is your problem those options should solve it.

Comment: I do not have sudo, it is not recognized.

Comment: try running `su -`   https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/354928/bash-sudo-command-not-found/354936

Comment: This works! What is the difference between `su` and `su -`?

Comment: Many useful things are in /sbin dirs which are in root's $PATH but not average users.  You can run them directly if you know what and where they are by specifying the full path to them.  Using su may not change your path but it can be changed by editing your ~/.profile.  You might want to add /usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin.  There's no harm in adding dirs that don't actually exist.